# How do I produce this sort of 3 D sound?

Tags: sound-effects-recording, sound-libraries, 3d

I recently came across this [audio](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B16F4aE0W_m6OFZRTVF2VlphRDQ/view?usp=sharing) (please hear the audio only with ear-phone/head phones). As said in the audio, it uses cetera algorithm. What that algorithm actually does? How does it work? I didn't get proper results in Google search.

I am asking the algorithm so that I can write a python/Matlab code which does that.

One thing I can say for now is that to differentiate between the source whether it is on my right side or left side, I can delay one of the sound signals by delta, where this delta = distance between a typical human ear/speed of sound in air. So I tried the following in Matlab

```
[y,fs,bits]= wavread('a2002011001-e02.wav');
left = y(:,1);
right = y(:,2);
clear y;

%delta = 0.000626822157 seconds and sampling frequency fs os 44100Hz
x = 0.000626822157/(2.2676e-05); %27.6425 ~ 28

left = [zeros(28,1); left]*0.9; %delay by 0.000626822157 seconds
right = [right; zeros(28,1)]; %add zeroes at end to make size of left vector and right vector equal

y=[left;right];
soundsc(y,fs)
```

Comment: You are trying to simulate ITD but you need to take IID into account too : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization#ITD_and_IID